# multiple logical operation in python

Tags: python

```py
getbase = input()
if getbase == 'b' or 'a' or 'c' or 'd':
    if getbase == 'b' or 'a':
        getnum = 2
    elif getbase == 'c' or 'd':
        getnum = 4
    else:
        getnum = 8
print(getnum)
```

based on this code it always return 2

I know I have to change the if blocks but still I am wondering why this happen in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if getbase == 'b' or getbase == 'a' or getbase == 'c'...
```

you have to  state what you are comparing each time

Comment: Oh now I see.. it's working like `if (getbase == 'b') or 'a'`... thank you for answering! :)

Comment: I personally prefer: `if getbase in {'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'}: ...`